# Setup creation of Word Addin using Setup Project

Tags: c#, ms-word, installation, add-in

I have created a `Word Addin` that accesses `local` resources besides other functionality. Now, I have stuck into its `setup` creation.

I have googled but din't find the relevant reference.

Comment: It is entirely unclear what you are asking.

Comment: how to create a setup for the same Addin @Chris

Comment: This is a very broad question and the question lacks detail (e.g. what add-in technology are you using, what setup tool are you planning to use, what have you done so far?